# Bug when deleting non-allocated memory with an impi library

Tags: c++, memory, compilation, mpi, dynamic-memory-allocation

Two arrays are being allocated in the body of one class method's if-statement, which is an input-dependent and in my case, it has never been True. Thus, in my case, these two arrays are never been allocated. But then destructor of this class deletes these two [unallocated] arrays.

I have never had any errors with this code (C++ MPI+OpenMP based) using different MPI libraries and C++ compilers, except when I started to use an impi library.

The code was running ok, until it reaches the end and then throws the message "BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES" with the exit code either 6 or 11.

I fixed this bug, but now I am just curious why this happens with impi and how it is possible to delete an unallocated array in the most safe way.

Comment: Can we see some code rather than description of what you did? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

> how it is possible to delete an unallocated array in the most safe way.

Always initialize your variables. In this case initialize pointers with `nullptr` which is safe to pass to `delete` later:

```
sometype *pointer = nullptr;
if( condition ) {
     pointer = new sometype[size];
     // dealing with it
}
...
delete [] pointer;
```

but even better to use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` which are properly default initailized and manage memory.